# google chrome has multiple processes , what about UI threads?

Tags: multithreading, user-interface

I have always read and worked off a single UI thread since having more than one will screw up message pumping etc etc.

I am answering my own question here but want to validate my understanding on Chrome browser which is known to have multiple processes ( one per tab ) - does it also accelerate some bit on the rendering part by employing multiple UI threads ?

My guess is it does NOT , but if it does It would be very interesting to know or look at some sample c# code to demo the same ( does not have to be web browser demo).

Any pointers in the multiple UI thread direction would help! thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I cant state definitively how Chrome handles the rendering threads - but I would assume that each tab has its own rendering thread. I wouldnt see the point of going through all the effort of process isolating the tabs, only to tie them all together on a common rendering thread. They would all have the opportunity to interfere with each other.

I implemented a 'chrome-style' browser using WPF - the application shell was a single process, then each 'tab' was a MAF AddIn running in a separate process. The rendering was all in child processes - there was nothing shared. Each AddIn returned an INativeHandleContract (a WPF control) which was passed across the process boundary.

The upshot of this, was that an exception ANYWHERE in a child tab, would only take down the tab, and could be detected by the parent process, giving it a chance to provide some feedback/reload the tab etc.

This document wasnt around when I achieved it, but after a quick browse I think it has some pointers:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909794.aspx

Kent Boogaart also lent a helpful hand
http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/06/maf-gymnastics-service-provider.html

You may also need this QFE from Microsoft to fix a bug in serialization you may experience when passing a WPF control across a process boundary:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB982638
In regards to MS Connect bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/467381/wpf-controls-cannot-be-passed-across-process-boundaries

Comment: Threads don't provide any isolation. You can't catch an exception from one thread and resume the process.

Comment: That's correct - which is why my code has "each 'tab' was a MAF AddIn running in a separate process" - allowing chrome-like resilience against unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse threads and processes.  Each process will have it's own ui thread, but likely also it's own message pump.

Comment: yeah i agree conceptually. The way google chrome integrates its all makes it even more interesting. If there is evetnually one process that does the coordination amongst others and if it owns a UI thread as well etc etc. hence the question.